# Javascript document.getElementById().value not matching textbox value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, passwords

I am trying to make a simple password confirm script with Javascript. I am a novice at Javascript and web development, so any help would be helpful.

I would like to compare two text inputs (eventually password inputs), if both are equal, then the submit button is enabled. Using StackOverflow and W3 tutorials, I cam up wit the following:

```
<head>
<script>
function displayPass()
{
document.getElementById("complete").innerHTML="Password recorded.<br>Pass1 = " + document.getElementById("pass1").value + ".<br>Pass2 = " + document.getElementById("pass2").value + ".";
}
function checkpass()
{
    document.getElementById("pass1out").innerHTML = document.getElementById("pass1").value;
    document.getElementById("pass2out").innerHTML = document.getElementById("pass2").value;
    if(document.getElementById("pass1").value==document.getElementById("pass2").value){
        document.getElementById("subbutton").disabled = false;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("subbutton").disabled = true;
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=5>
<tr><td>Password</td><td><input id="pass1" type=text onkeypress="checkpass()"></input></td><td id=pass1out></td></tr>
<tr><td>Confirm</td><td><input id="pass2" type=text onkeypress="checkpass()"></input></td><td id=pass2out></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td><button type="button" id="subbutton" onclick="displayPass()" disabled>Submit</button></td></tr>
</table>
<p id="complete">&nbsp</p>
</body>
```

What I have noticed is that the values that are found in the text boxes in the checkpass() function does not match the actual value in the text box. It seems like it is one character behind.

When the button is enabled and I click submit, the values in displayPass() are correct and match the vaules in the text boxes.

I don't know if I am missing something simple, of if I goes deeper in Javascript usage. I've seen similar post where they recommend using jQuery, but I have not gotten that far to use jQuery yet.

Comment: Use `keyup` instead of `keypress`.  You're right about it being a character behind, but the keyup event happens after the value has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can get required output using following code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function displayPass()
{
document.getElementById("complete").innerHTML="Password recorded.<br>Pass1 = " +      document.getElementById("pass1").value + ".<br>Pass2 = " + document.getElementById("pass2").value + ".";
}
function checkpass()
{
document.getElementById("pass1out").innerHTML = document.getElementById("pass1").value;
document.getElementById("pass2out").innerHTML = document.getElementById("pass2").value;
if(document.getElementById("pass1").value==document.getElementById("pass2").value){
    document.getElementById("subbutton").disabled = false;
} else {
    document.getElementById("subbutton").disabled = true;
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=5>
<tr><td>Password</td><td><input id="pass1" type=text onkeyup="checkpass()"></input></td><td id=pass1out></td></tr>
<tr><td>Confirm</td><td><input id="pass2" type=text onkeyup="checkpass()"></input></td><td id=pass2out></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td><button type="button" id="subbutton" onclick="displayPass()" disabled>Submit</button></td></tr>
</table>
<p id="complete">&nbsp</p>
</body>
<html>
```

User "onkeyup" instead of "keypress"

Comment: "Gimme reputation!" can't blame you.